# How can i get value from 3 table Joined with FK in Blade view

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

table : projects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWUk.png)

table : projects_departments[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgMy8.png)
table : departments[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsUEs.png)

This is Model Project

```
public function projects_departments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Project_department::class); 
}
```

This is Model Project_department

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

This is Model Department

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
}

public function projects_departments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Project_department::class); 
}
```

this is my blade

```
project->departments->department_name
```

This is MY error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'projects_departments.project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `projects_departments` where `projects_departments`.`project_id` = 48 and `projects_departments`.`project_id` is not null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$project = DB::table('projects')
        ->select(*)
        ->join('Department', 'projects_departments.department_id', '=', 'Department.id')
        ->join('projects_departments', 'projects_departments.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')

        ->get();
```

let's try this one

Comment: @WisarutChuwet Did u get the answer? Then marked it as a answer